# Assign click events to D3 chart elements using Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, d3.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I want to bind click events to points created by a chart instantiated by a Backbone View, but events and delegateEvents aren't working (ie, no event is fired on clicking '.point' elements):

```
// View
var ScatterView = Backbone.View.extend({
    defaults:{
        // height, width, etc.
        },
    events:{
        'click .point':'clickFunction'
    }, 
    clickFunction:function() {
        console.log('clicked')
    },
    initialize:function(options) {
        this.options = _.extend({}, this.defaults, options)
        this.render()
    },
    render:function() {
        var that = this
        this.chart = new Scatter({
        container:that.el.id, 
            // pass parameters: width, height, etc.
        })

    this.delegateEvents()
    }
})

// Scatter function 
var Scatter = function(settings) {
    this.settings = settings
    this.build()
}


Scatter.prototype.build = function() {
    // Bind points
    this.div = d3.select('#' + settings.container).append('div').attr('id', settings.id).attr('class', 'chart')
    this.g = this.div.append('g')
    this.points = this.g.selectAll('.point')
                .data(this.data, function(d) {return d.id})
                .enter().append('circle')
                .attr('cx', function(d) {return that.xScale(d.x)})
                .attr('cy', function(d) {return that.yScale(d.y)})
                .attr('r', that.settings.radius)
                .attr('class', 'point')
}

// instantiate view
var sv = new ScatterView({model:sm, el:'#main', chartid:'scatter-' + d, textid:'text-' + d})
```

Comment: I don't see where you're adding the `point` class to any element.

Comment: Sorry, that was in the "circleFunction" call -- i've edited it above.

Comment: Is your chart even rendering? It looks like you're embedding sag elements `<g>`, `<circle>` directly within html `<div>` containers. That's certainly not valid html, so I'm a bit surprised you're seeing the chart at all.

Comment: The chart is rendering just fine - I often embed svg, g, circle, rect elements within a div without issue

Comment: interesting. it's not valid, so I wouldn't recommend it. would be safer to embed SVG within an `<svg>` element to make it valid. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an `el` property, for example:

```
var ScatterView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#chartContainer', ...
});
```

Comment: I pass the argument in view instantiation (updated question).  Still doesn't work... I also tried assigning it directly, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
events:{
  "click [class~=point]" : "clickFunction"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that Backbone uses jQuery event binding under the covers, but you're trying to set click events on SVG elements. Without additional plugins, jQuery won't reliably select SVG elements, so there's no way it can bind events to them.

Comment: When I run this line explicitly ($("#main .point").on('click', function(){}) it works just fine -- somehow it isn't binding properly or at the right time -- not sure why

Comment: Yes, but unless jQuery has added better support for SVG recently (and I don't see any notice in the release notes), you're gonna have problems. See [here](http://www.benknowscode.com/2012/09/using-svg-elements-with-jquery_6812.html) or [here](http://blag.oztechninja.com/post/25699330571/simple-svg-manipulation-with-jquery).